# #1054 - Unknown column 'id.especialidades' in 'where clause'

Tags: where-clause

Why does the query give me this error: #1054 - Unknown column 'id.especialidades' in 'where clause'

```
SELECT *

FROM medicos, especialidades

WHERE id.especialidades = id_esp.medicos;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can refer to a column as **col_name**, **tbl_name.col_name**, or **db_name.tbl_name.col_name**. You need not specify a **tbl_name** or **db_name.tbl_name** prefix for a column reference unless the reference would be ambiguous. Refer to [MySQL ::   MySQL 5.0 Reference Manual :: 13.2.8 SELECT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)

The table name should precede the column name.

```
SELECT * FROM medicos, especialidades
WHERE especialidades.id = medicos.id_esp;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have conditions written backward. Format `[table_name/alias].[attribute]`

```
SELECT *

FROM medicos, especialidades

WHERE especialidades.id = medicos.id_esp;
```